# Pandas convert some value in row into columns

Tags: python

I have a problem in python. The table looks like the following table I have columns values from 1 to 6: the values are random just to show the general idea

| time | sensor | sample | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 | value5 | value6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22.10 | ACCX | 6 | 0.23 | 0.44 | 0.53 | 0.23 | 0.44 | 0.53 |
| 22.10 | ACCY | 6 | 0.87 | 0.32 | 0.12 | 0.87 | 0.32 | 0.12 |
| 22.10 | ACCZ | 6 | 0.44 | 0.33 | 0.45 | 0.63 | 0.44 | 0.93 |
| 22.12 | ACCX | 6 | 0.63 | 0.44 | 0.93 | 0.87 | 0.32 | 0.12 |
| 22.12 | ACCY | 6 | 0.87 | 0.32 | 0.12 | 0.44 | 0.33 | 0.45 |
| 22.12 | ACCZ | 6 | 0.44 | 0.33 | 0.45 | 0.34 | 0.22 | 0.78 |
| 22.15 | ACCX | 6 | 0.23 | 0.44 | 0.53 | 0.64 | 0.53 | 0.25 |
| 22.15 | ACCY | 6 | 0.87 | 0.32 | 0.12 | 0.87 | 0.32 | 0.12 |
| 22.15 | ACCZ | 6 | 0.44 | 0.33 | 0.45 | 0.44 | 0.33 | 0.45 |
| 22.18 | ACCX | 6 | 0.63 | 0.44 | 0.93 | 0.87 | 0.32 | 0.12 |
| 22.18 | ACCY | 6 | 0.87 | 0.32 | 0.12 | 0.44 | 0.33 | 0.45 |
| 22.18 | ACCZ | 6 | 0.44 | 0.33 | 0.45 | 0.87 | 0.32 | 0.12 |

And I need to convert rows that have same the time and sensor to columns. I need all rows with date and sensor to appear like this where the date will be repeated 6 times:

| time | ACCX | ACCY | ACCZ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22.10 | 0.23 | 0.44 | 0.23 |
| 22.10 | 0.87 | 0.32 | 0.12 |
| 22.10 | 0.44 | 0.33 | 0.45 |
| 22.10 | 0.23 | 0.44 | 0.23 |
| 22.10 | 0.87 | 0.32 | 0.12 |
| 22.10 | 0.44 | 0.33 | 0.45 |
| 22.12 | 0.23 | 0.44 | 0.53 |
| 22.12 | 0.87 | 0.32 | 0.12 |
| 22.12 | 0.44 | 0.33 | 0.45 |
| 22.12 | 0.44 | 0.33 | 0.45 |
| 22.12 | 0.63 | 0.44 | 0.93 |
| 22.12 | 0.87 | 0.32 | 0.12 |
| 22.15 | 0.44 | 0.33 | 0.45 |
| 22.15 | 0.23 | 0.44 | 0.53 |
| 22.15 | 0.87 | 0.32 | 0.12 |
| 22.15 | 0.44 | 0.33 | 0.45 |
| 22.15 | 0.63 | 0.44 | 0.93 |
| 22.15 | 0.87 | 0.32 | 0.12 |
| 22.18 | 0.44 | 0.33 | 0.45 |
| 22.18 | 0.44 | 0.33 | 0.45 |
| 22.18 | 0.63 | 0.44 | 0.93 |
| 22.18 | 0.87 | 0.32 | 0.12 |
| 22.18 | 0.44 | 0.33 | 0.45 |
| 22.18 | 0.44 | 0.33 | 0.45 |

Comment: Your expected output looks odd: the values don't correspond to the right columns (`sensors`): is that intended?

Comment: the values are random I just need to convert the rows into columns

Comment: Providing the code, you have done so far would be very appreciated and helps us to start with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First drag the `valueN` items into a column (together with the resp. column labels) by `.melt`ing the dataframe, then `.pivot` the `sensor`s into the columns, and do some cleaning up:

```py
res = (
    df.drop(columns="sample")
    .melt(id_vars=["time", "sensor"])
    .pivot(index=["time", "variable"], columns="sensor")
    .droplevel(-1).reset_index()
    .droplevel(0, axis=1).rename(columns={"": "time"})
)
```

But: The result for your sample doesn't look like the expected result (the values)?

Comment: Thanks a million, that is exactly what I need. Sorry for the  creepy  question

Comment: shorturl.at/grQZ4
convert the time column the first table shows the correct output
df['time'] = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f") for x in df['time']]
after converting the table, I got the wrong output of the time column where the time has the same value for all the records
df = ( 

   df.drop(columns="sample")
  .melt(id_vars=["time", "sensor"])
  .pivot(index=["time", "variable"], columns="sensor")
  .droplevel(-1).reset_index()
  .droplevel(0, axis=1).rename(columns={"": "time"}))
print(df.head())